# extra object being created in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

EDIT: THIS IS HAPPENING IN DEVELOPMENT, BUT NOT IN PRODUCTION. The reason why it's a problem is because I when I add `school.tuition + school.room_and_board` for my table, it says that '+' is an invalid operator an an object named nil.  Again, this only happens in development, not production.  Still, it's a problem because I'd like to be able to still work in the development environment.

See http://www.collegeanswerz.com/colleges, and then go to size.  You'll see that under national universities, there's an extra College object being created.  I can't figure out why.

(Note: you don't see this in alphabetical or rank because that code is manual html, rather than rails iteration)

I just added 100 more schools today.  Previously, there wasn't an extra object being created.  Now there is.

`seeds.rb`

```
@college = College.find_or_create_by_name!('University of Pittsburgh')
if @college.update_attributes(
    url: 'university-of-pittsburgh',
    public: 'Public',
    years: '4-year',
    category: 'National University',
    calendar: 'Semester',
    location: 'Pittsburgh, PA',
    setting: 'Large City (250-500k)',
    degrees: 'Certificate, Bachelors, Masters, Doctoral',
    rotc: 'Air Force, Army, Navy',
    very_important: 'Academic GPA|Rigor of secondary school record|Standardized Test Scores',
    considered: 'Application Essay|Character/Personal Qualities|Class Rank|Extracurricular Activities|First Generation College Student|Geographical Residence|Level of Applicant\'s Interest|Racial/Ethnic Status|Recommendations|State Residency|Talent/Ability|Volunteer Work|Work Experience',
    student_faculty: '14 to 1',
    retention: '90',
    graduation4: '57',
    graduation6: '79',
    sat_submit: '89',
    act_submit: '41',
    sat_math_25: '600',
    sat_math_75: '690',
    sat_reading_25: '570',
    sat_reading_75: '690',
    sat_writing_25: '560',
    sat_writing_75: '660',
    sat_composite_25: '1130',
    sat_composite_75: '1320',
    act_math_25: '25',
    act_math_75: '30',
    act_english_25: '25',
    act_english_75: '31',
    act_writing_25: '7',
    act_writing_75: '9',
    act_composite_25: '25',
    act_composite_75: '30',
    acceptance_rate: '58',
    enrolled: '32',
    gpa375: '71',
    gpa35: '15',
    gpa325: '8',
    gpa3: '4',
    gpa25: '2',
    high_school_tenth: '54',
    high_school_quarter: '86',
    high_school_half: '99',
    sat_math_700: '25',
    sat_math_600: '53',
    sat_math_500: '21',
    sat_math_400: '1',
    sat_math_300: '0',
    sat_reading_700: '24',
    sat_reading_600: '42',
    sat_reading_500: '32',
    sat_reading_400: '2',
    sat_reading_300: '0',
    sat_writing_700: '14',
    sat_writing_600: '45',
    sat_writing_500: '37',
    sat_writing_400: '4',
    sat_writing_300: '0',
    act_composite_30: '33',
    act_composite_24: '58',
    act_composite_18: '8',
    act_composite_12: '1',
    act_math_30: '40',
    act_math_24: '46',
    act_math_18: '13',
    act_math_12: '1',
    act_english_30: '0',
    act_english_24: '0',
    act_english_18: '0',
    act_english_12: '0',
    class_20: '42',
    class_49: '39.6',
    class_50: '18.4',
    majors: 'business/marketing: 15%|social sciences: 14%|health professions: 11%|english: 10%|engineering: 9%|psychology: 8%|biology: 7%|history: 5%',
    law: '3',
    business: '1',
    medical: '4',
    other_grad: '28',
    us_news_ranking: '58',
    top_25_grad: 'Physical Therapy (3)|Speech-Language Pathology (8)|Library and Information Studies (10)|Social Work (11)|Medicine (15)|Education (24)',
    requirements: 'http://www.asundergrad.pitt.edu/requirements/gened.html',
    majors_offered_link: 'http://www.pitt.edu/academics/undergraduate',
    ap_credit: 'http://www.oafa.pitt.edu/pdf/CreditAPIBExam.pdf',
    enrollment: '18427',
    graduate_enrollment: '10339',
    in_state: '68',
    out_of_state: '32',
    male: '49',
    female: '51',
    ethnicity: 'white: 77%|hispanic/latino: 2%|asian: 8%|black: 5%|2 or more races: 3%|non-resident aliens: 3%|other: 2%',
    frats: '12',
    sororities: '10',
    on_campus: '45',
    freshman_on_campus: '97',
    in_state_tuition: '16590',
    out_of_state_tuition: '26280',
    room_and_board: '9870',
    with_need_got_aid: '68',
    got_need_fully_met: '7',
    percent_need_met: '59',
    scholarships: '41',
    loans: '59',
    cost_30: '17326',
    cost_48: '19950',
    cost_75: '23636',
    cost_110: '26410',
    cost_111: '26985',
    scholarships_link: 'http://www.oafa.pitt.edu/universityschlrs.aspx',
    map: '<iframe width="900" height="1150" scrolling="no" src="http://www.tour.pitt.edu/campus-map"></iframe>',
    street_view: '<iframe width="900" height="550" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=embed&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=University+of+Pittsburgh,+4200+Fifth+Ave,+Pittsburgh,+PA&amp;aq=0&amp;oq=uni&amp;sll=40.444261,-79.970448&amp;sspn=0.142165,0.251656&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=University+of+Pittsburgh,+4200+Fifth+Ave,+Pittsburgh,+PA&amp;ll=40.443486,-79.958245&amp;spn=0.010798,0.021038&amp;t=m&amp;layer=c&amp;cbll=40.441775,-79.956671&amp;panoid=BgWQKMiSI1fpwP7JUF16Vg&amp;cbp=12,45.25,,0,-3.34&amp;output=svembed"></iframe><br /><small><a href="https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=embed&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=University+of+Pittsburgh,+4200+Fifth+Ave,+Pittsburgh,+PA&amp;aq=0&amp;oq=uni&amp;sll=40.431368,-79.9805&amp;sspn=0.142165,0.251656&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=University+of+Pittsburgh,+4200+Fifth+Ave,+Pittsburgh,+PA&amp;ll=40.443486,-79.958245&amp;spn=0.010798,0.021038&amp;t=m&amp;layer=c&amp;cbll=40.441775,-79.956671&amp;panoid=BgWQKMiSI1fpwP7JUF16Vg&amp;cbp=12,45.25,,0,-3.34" style="color:#0000FF;text-align:left">View Larger Map</a></small>',
    housing: '<iframe src="http://www.tour.pitt.edu/tour-categories/residence-halls" scrolling="no" height="820" width="900"></iframe>',
    food: '<div style="overflow: hidden; max-width: 1000px;"><iframe scrolling="no" src="http://www.pc.pitt.edu/dining/menus.php" style="margin-left: 0; height: 2000px; margin-top: -370px; margin-bottom: -375px; width: 750px;"></iframe></div>',
    weather: '<div style="overflow: hidden; max-width: 500px;"><iframe scrolling="no" src="http://www.weather.com/weather/wxclimatology/monthly/graph/USPA1290" style="margin-left: -40px; height: 1570px; margin-top: -490px; width: 500px;"></iframe></div>',
    dorms: 'Towers (fr.)|Sutherland (fr.)|Lothrop (fr.)|Nordenberg (fr.)|Holland (fr.)|Forbes (fr.; honors)|McCormick|Brackenridge|Amos|Bruce|Panther|Pennsylvania|Ruskin|Bouquet Gardens|Oakwood Apartments|Centre-Plaza Apartments|Forbes-Craig Apartments (honors)',
    dorm_urls: 'towers|sutherland|lothrop|nordenberg|holland|forbes|mccormick|brackenridge|amos|bruce|panther|pennsylvania|ruskin|bouquet-gardens|oakwood-apartments|centre-plaza-apartments|forbes-craig-apartments',
    science_majors: 'Actuarial Science|Agriculture|Applied Math|Astronomy|Biology|Chemistry|Computer Science|Earth Science|Geology|Linguistics|Mathematics|Neuroscience|Physics|Statistics',
    social_science_majors: 'Anthropology|Criminology|Economics|History|Political Science|Psychology|Sociology|Urban Studies|Women\'s Studies',
    humanities_majors: 'Art|Classics|English|Film|History and Philosophy of Science|Literature|Music|Philosophy|Religious Studies|Theatre',
    business_majors: 'Accounting|Finance|Management|Marketing',
    engineering_majors: 'Bioengineering|Chemical|Civil|Computer|Electrical|Engineering Science|Industrial|Materials Science and Engineering|Mechanical|Nuclear',
    professional_majors: 'Architecture|Athletic Training|Communications/ Journalism|Information Science|Nursing|Nutrition|Pharmacy|Public Health|Rehab Science|Social Work',
    area_studies_majors: 'African|Chinese|French|German|Italian|Japanese|Jewish|Latin American|Middle Eastern|Russian|Spanish|Other')
else
  # handle validation errors
end
```

My seeds file is basically that for 300 schools.  I looked through it a ton of times and I don't see anything that should create an empty object.  I used cmd + f to look for variations of `@college = College.find_or_create_by_name!('')`, but there's nothing.  I manually went through all the cmd + f 's for `@college = College.find_or_create_by_name!(`, and they all are creating an actual college with a name (the empty object doesn't have a name).

Here are some relevant excerpts of code.  Let me know if you want to see more.

Any ideas about what the problem is?

`static_pages_controller.rb`

```
def colleges
    @national_university = College.where("category = 'National University'").order("enrollment DESC")
    @liberal_arts_college = College.where("category = 'Liberal Arts College' OR category = 'Military College'").order("enrollment DESC")
  end
```

`colleges.html.erb`

```
<div class="tab-pane" id="size">
        <h3>National Universities</h3>
        <nav class="list">
            <ol>
                <% @national_university.each do |school| %>
                    <li><%= link_to "#{school.name} (#{(number_with_delimiter(school.enrollment, :delimiter => ',') )})", "/#{school.url}" %></li>
                <% end %>
            </ol>
        </nav>

        <h3>Liberal Arts Colleges</h3>
        <nav class="list">
            <ol>
                <% @liberal_arts_college.each do |school| %>
                    <li><%= link_to "#{school.name} (#{(number_with_delimiter(school.enrollment, :delimiter => ',') )})", "/#{school.url}" %></li>
                <% end %>
            </ol>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="table">
        <div class="tabbable">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                <li class="active"><a href="#national_universities" data-toggle="tab">National Universities</a></li>
                <li><a href="#liberal_arts_colleges" data-toggle="tab">Liberal Arts Colleges</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div id="national_universities" class="tab-pane active">
                <table id="national_universities_table" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Rank</th>
                            <th>Location</th>
                            <th>Setting</th>
                            <th>Size</th>
                            <th>Cost*</th>
                            <th>Math SAT</th>
                            <th>Reading SAT</th>
                            <th>ACT Composite</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <% @national_university.each do |school| %>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="name_column"><%= link_to "#{school.name}", "#{school.url}" %></td>
                                <td class="rank_column"><%= "#{school.us_news_ranking}" %></td>
                                <td class="location_column"><%= "#{school.location}" %></td>
                                <td class="setting_column"><%= "#{school.setting}" %></td>
                                <td class="size_column"><%= number_with_delimiter("#{school.enrollment}", :delimiter => ',') %></td>
                                <td class="cost_column">$<%= number_with_delimiter("#{school.in_state_tuition}", :delimiter => ',') %>
                                / $<%= number_with_delimiter("#{school.out_of_state_tuition}", :delimiter => ',') %></td>
                                <td class="math_column"><%= "#{school.sat_math_25} - #{school.sat_math_75}" %></td>
                                <td><%= "#{school.sat_reading_25} - #{school.sat_reading_75}" %></td>
                                <td><%= "#{school.act_composite_25} - #{school.act_composite_75}" %></td>
                            </tr>
                        <% end %>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div> <!-- pane 1 -->

            <div id="liberal_arts_colleges" class="tab-pane">
                <table id="liberal_arts_colleges_table" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Rank</th>
                            <th>Location</th>
                            <th>Setting</th>
                            <th>Size</th>
                            <th>Cost*</th>
                            <th>Math SAT</th>
                            <th>Reading SAT</th>
                            <th>ACT Composite</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <% @liberal_arts_college.each do |school| %>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="name_column"><%= link_to "#{school.name}", "#{school.url}" %></td>
                                <td class="rank_column"><%= "#{school.us_news_ranking}" %></td>
                                <td class="location_column"><%= "#{school.location}" %></td>
                                <td class="setting_column"><%= "#{school.setting}" %></td>
                                <td class="size_column"><%= number_with_delimiter("#{school.enrollment}", :delimiter => ',') %></td>
                                <td class="cost_column">$<%= number_with_delimiter("#{school.in_state_tuition + school.room_and_board}", :delimiter => ',') %>
                                / $<%= number_with_delimiter("#{school.out_of_state_tuition + school.room_and_board}", :delimiter => ',') %></td>
                                <td class="math_column"><%= "#{school.sat_math_25} - #{school.sat_math_75}" %></td>
                                <td><%= "#{school.sat_reading_25} - #{school.sat_reading_75}" %></td>
                                <td><%= "#{school.act_composite_25} - #{school.act_composite_75}" %></td>
                            </tr>
                        <% end %>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div> <!-- pane 2-->

            <p>Tip: Sort multiple columns simultaneously by holding down the shift key and clicking a second, third or even fourth column header!</p>
            <p>*cost = tuition + room & board; in state / out of state</p>
        </div>  <!-- tab-content -->
    </div> <!-- tab-pane -->
```

console output during attempt to delete empty object

```
:002 > College.where("name=''")
  College Load (5.6ms)  SELECT "colleges".* FROM "colleges" WHERE (name='')
 => [#<College id: 201, public: "Public", years: "4-year", category: "National University", calendar: "", location: "", setting: "", retention: nil, created_at: "2013-08-02 20:26:53", updated_at: "2013-08-02 20:26:53", graduation4: nil, graduation6: nil, degrees: "", rotc: "", sat_submit: nil, act_submit: nil, sat_math_25: nil, sat_math_75: nil, sat_reading_25: nil, sat_reading_75: nil, sat_writing_25: nil, sat_writing_75: nil, sat_composite_25: nil, sat_composite_75: nil, act_math_25: nil, act_math_75: nil, act_writing_75: nil, act_composite_25: nil, act_composite_75: nil, acceptance_rate: nil, enrolled: nil, gpa375: nil, gpa35: nil, gpa325: nil, gpa3: nil, gpa25: nil, high_school_tenth: nil, high_school_quarter: nil, high_school_half: nil, sat_math_700: nil, sat_math_600: nil, sat_math_500: nil, sat_math_400: nil, sat_math_300: nil, sat_reading_700: nil, sat_reading_600: nil, sat_reading_500: nil, sat_reading_400: nil, sat_reading_300: nil, sat_writing_700: nil, sat_writing_600: nil, sat_writing_500: nil, sat_writing_400: nil, sat_writing_300: nil, act_composite_30: nil, act_composite_24: nil, act_composite_18: nil, act_composite_12: nil, act_math_30: nil, act_math_24: nil, act_math_18: nil, act_math_12: nil, very_important: "", important: nil, considered: "", student_faculty: "", class_20: nil, class_49: nil, class_50: nil, majors: "", law: nil, business: nil, medical: nil, other_grad: nil, us_news_ranking: nil, top_25_grad: "", enrollment: nil, graduate_enrollment: nil, in_state: nil, out_of_state: nil, male: nil, female: nil, ethnicity: "", frats: nil, sororities: nil, on_campus: nil, freshman_on_campus: nil, in_state_tuition: nil, out_of_state_tuition: nil, room_and_board: nil, with_need_got_aid: nil, got_need_fully_met: nil, percent_need_met: nil, scholarships: nil, loans: nil, name: "", url: "", act_writing_25: nil, cost_30: nil, cost_48: nil, cost_75: nil, cost_110: nil, cost_111: nil, requirements: "", majors_offered: nil, ap_credit: "", scholarships_link: "", map: "", street_view: "", housing: "", food: "", weather: "", dorms: "", majors_offered_link: "", science_majors: "Actuarial Science|Agriculture|Applied Math|Astronom...", social_science_majors: "Anthropology|Criminology|Economics|History|Politica...", humanities_majors: "Art|Classics|English|Film|History and Philosophy of...", business_majors: "Accounting|Finance|Management|Marketing", engineering_majors: "Bioengineering|Chemical|Civil|Computer|Electrical|E...", professional_majors: "Architecture|Athletic Training|Communications/ Jour...", dorm_urls: "", act_english_25: nil, act_english_75: nil, act_english_30: nil, act_english_24: nil, act_english_18: nil, act_english_12: nil, area_studies_majors: "African|Chinese|French|German|Italian|Japanese|Jewi...">] 
1.9.3p429 :003 > College.where("name=''").destroy
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
    from /Users/adamzerner/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/relation.rb:378:in `destroy'
    from (irb):3
    from /Users/adamzerner/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
    from /Users/adamzerner/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /Users/adamzerner/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
1.9.3p429 :004 > College.where("name=''").delete
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
    from /Users/adamzerner/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/relation.rb:440:in `delete'
    from (irb):4
    from /Users/adamzerner/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
    from /Users/adamzerner/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /Users/adamzerner/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
1.9.3p429 :005 >
```

Comment: Have you tried entering rails console and searching for the empty object?  Figure out what the id number is and when it is being inserted (after which particular college).  Then look for it in the seeds.rb file?

Comment: That's your data model and how you seed?! In any case, obviously there's no way we can diagnose with the information provided.

Comment: @DaveNewton Yea, it's my first rails app.. I'm not really sure what else to do.  This way is easy to input data, and that's important because I have 300 schools.  And yea, I know it's not much info, but I'm not sure what else to say.

Comment: @Nick Your method seems to be close to solving this issue.  When I did College.where, it found an empty object.  I think the issue is that I may have created one yesterday by accident and ran `rake db:seed`, and then took the empty object out of my seed file, but when I subsequently ran `rake db:seed` the old empty object remained.

I am now trying to delete this empty object, but it's not working.  See the edit to my question for console output.  Do you know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @AdamZerner `where` is returning you a list.  Use `College.where("name=''").each { |a| a.destroy }`.  Btw, you should add validations to ensure empty strings don't get saved. :)

Comment: thanks @Nick, that worked and it fixed my problem.  do you want to write this up as an answer and I'll select it as the best answer (so you can get credit)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion from the above comment was to look in the rails console for the object with the empty string as its name.  It can help you figure out where/when/how the object was being inserted.

Once you figure that out, you can get rid of all the "nameless" objects by:

```
College.where("name=''").each { |a| a.destroy }
```

-Nick